# Power BI: User Permission to create Dashboards from shared reports only

Tags: powerbi, dashboard

I need to achieve the following scenario in the Power BI Service: Power BI Users need to be able to create dashboards from the reports which have been shared with them.

I cannot give them access to the whole workspace, because the workspace also contains reports which they are not supposed to see. Giving them access on the workspace level will reveal all contents.

If I share only individual reports from a workspace with them, they can view the report, but cannot pin its contents to a dashboard. In this case, the "Pin" is greyed out and the are told that "Read-only content can't be pinned". I have given them permissions to read and create content when I shared the report with them.

Can anyone please provide any help / insight on this? This does not seem like an outlandish requirement.

Comment: You can't do it via shared reports. It will be workspace access only, to create a dashboard. You also can't create a dashboard with reports from other workspaces, just the same workspace

Comment: Hello @Jon. Thanks for the reply. Sadly, you are right. I will leave a suggestion at ideas.powerbi.com. Maybe there could be something like personla dashboards, which can be created based upon shared reports and are not tied to a specific workspace.